# Amd graphics card installation error on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon

after downloading the amd-driver-installer-15.20.1046-x86.x86_64.run from the amd site 
i delete old versions before installation process 
according to this post [ati-driver-re-install-fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98827/ati-driver-re-install-fail)

after i enter this command sudo ./amd-driver-installer-15.20.1046-x86.x86_64.run 
i got an error message :
''Please install the required prerequisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation.''
[screenshot to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEhEP.png<br)

when i enter to the log file i get :

> NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for
>   installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve
>   package-dependency issues.
>  fglrx installation requires that the
>   system has kernel headers. 
>   /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be
>   found on this system.

how can i solve this problem [version.h cannot be found on this system] ?

> Install kernel headers using the command apt-get install
>   linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic.
>  already i have the newest
>   version of linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic

Can any one tell me what is the prerequisites needed to start the installation process?

Comment: The message clearly says you need to check the log for details.

Comment: @mikewhatever alraedy i checked the log file but i can't solve the problem . i edit the question by adding the content of the log file.

Answer (score 3):

You have all the prerequisites installed already the problem is that in newer versions of the kernel the version.h file has been relocated.
You can locate it with

```
locate version.h
```

Which most likely will come up with this location for your version.h file for that version of the kernel "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h". But since we already know which kernel version and what distro you are using all you have to do is link the missing file to the folder and start the installation again.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
```

That should work. Unless AMD is still not supporting that version of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem. Just 
touch /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
 file in folder in logfile.