# How do I verify that Ubuntu recognizes my discrete graphics card (Radeon HD8750M)?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon

My lenovo g500h has integrated intel 4000hd graphics card and discrete ati hd8750m radeon card. 
It looks like by default the intel graphics driver is installed ( when i type lspci | grep VGA in terminal, it says - VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09))

So how can i know whether linux sees my discrete card? 
And how can i know whether the amd drivers i find, are the right ones?
I found these - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064 ,but it says its for Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

All in all, what is the overall process to install hybrid graphics on my PC? Where should i start? 
I spent some time earlier on this, but couldn't find any good aggregated information.

Comment: It says 'Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 14.04.2' supported NOT 15.10. but i will say it should work on 15.10 also...give it a try

Comment: Had problems when building .deb packages, but understood that others have the same problem with Ubuntu 15.10. Will try to fix problem by referring to this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/702484/how-to-build-ati-crimson-driver-on-ubuntu-15-10.

Comment: You seem to have more than one question in mind. Please ask separate questions for clearer answers.

Comment: Since intel 4000hd satisfied my needs in linux,  in the end i stayed without the discrete card. What can i tell is that it is not that hard to get it working, there were some bugs though... From my experience, backup all the important stuff on your system before you start tinkering around.