# Ubuntu 16.04 and AMD Graphics

Tags: drivers, radeon, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have a Radeon HD6950 and I want to install `amd-catalyst-15.9-linux-installer-15.201.1151.x86.x86_64.zip` but every time I will to do this the terminal just says

```
ERROR: Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.78A2iR
```

In this log just stay

```
fglrx installation requires that the system has kernel headers.  /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
Install kernel headers using the command apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic.
```

But I installed this packages?

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg-query -s linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic | grep -e '^Status:'`?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with a Radeon HD4250. The problem is that there is no version.h file inside the /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/build/include/linux directory. This is because in newer versions of the kernel the version.h file has been relocated. You can locate it with:

```
locate version.h
```

Since we already know which kernel version and what distro you are using all you have to do is link the missing file to the folder and start the installation again.

Source: [Amd graphics card installation error on ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697265/amd-graphics-card-installation-error-on-ubuntu-15-10)